# How do I stop notifications about my wife's Airpods being "detected near me"?

Tags: ios, notifications, geolocation, airpods, airtag

When Apple released the AirTag, they made a big deal about safety features to help prevent stalking. If there's an unknown AirTag or other location-enabled device traveling with you, your iPhone will notify you.

Unfortunately, this means that when my wife and I travel anywhere, I get a notification saying "Airpods Pro detected near you". There's an option to "pause safety alerts", but this only stops the notifications for one day.

How can I make my iPhone stop notifying me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaume's suggestion in the comments worked for me. I paired the Airpods with my own phone, and the notifications stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You can pause them indefinitely if you and your wife are in an iCloud Family group.

The option will appear alongside the option you already mentioned.

Comment: Does that work for accessories other than AirTags? According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227#message, you can only turn off safety alerts indefinitely for AirTags.

Comment: I assume so, as my wife doesn't get alerts about my AirTags or AirPods Pro and I don't get alerts about her AirPods or AirTags. We are in an iCloud Family group.

Comment: Yes, I used this to silence AirPods as well